# Hive truncate table only when it's not empty

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive job that is scheduled to be executed. At the beginning of the job, I want to truncate a table by doing:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SOMETABLE
```

The problem is that the table may be empty. In that case, I don't want to perform the truncate operation which will raise an exception. I know in MySQL you can do something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE)
BEGIN 
TRUNCATE SOMETABLE
END
```

Is there a way I can achieve something similar in hive? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What exception do you get on truncate of empty table?

Comment: The table may be empty because its _LOCATION_ directory contains no file. Or because the directory contains multiple, empty data files. In the second case, removing these useless files before INSERTing new data  will improve performance, hence TRUNCATE is beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table **is empty** also hive **won't raise any exception**.

You can also make use of **Temporary tables** in hive so that these tables only accessible through the session that established and very **useful to manage intermediate** data.
Once the session got closed then **Hive deletes all temporary tables**.

Please refer [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/9337/hive-temporary-tables.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385163/create-temporary-table-in-hive) links regarding hive temporary tables.